# google drive URL parameters

Tags: google-drive-api, url-parameters

I've got some video files on google drive, and I was delighted to find that I can share the video with a URL parameter that looks like (for example...) "https://drive.google.com/file/d/longUniqueIdentifier/view?t=10m6s". I was particularly interested in the /view parameter, and hopefully other related video parameters. HOWEVER, I cannot find any documentation anywhere on what other parameters are available, or indeed any documentation on the /view parameter. Has anyone found this ? I have come across several other people looking for this information, but no answers. What's up google ?

Comment: `/view` corresponds to the URL to share non-Google Documents. In Google Documents, it usually ends with `/edit`. Additional parameters depend on the file type (for example, `t` for videos). But there is no official documentation about these as far as I know. I'd suggest you to request it via `Support > Send feedback` at https://drive.google.com/.

Comment: Thx lamblichus...no documentation seems kind of unbelievable...